# is there a better way to test value exists in nested array using twig

Tags: php, twig

I have a modal that has buttons rendered by twig using this data array

```
"buttons" => [
    [
        "title" => "Copy",
        "type" => "button",
        "attributes" => [
            "data-action" => "confirm"
        ],
        "class" => "btn-primary",
    ],
    [
        "title" => "Cancel",
        "type" => "button",
        "attributes" => [
            "aria-label" => "Close"
        ],
        "class" => "btn-light",
    ]
]
```

I want the modal to not show a [x] in the top corner, if there is already a button with the attribute "aria-labal='Close'", so I added this nested set of if statements and for loops.

```
{% set hideBtnClear = false %}
{% for btn in modal.buttons %}
    {% if btn.attributes %}
        {% for key, value in btn.attributes %}
            {% if key == "aria-label" and value == "Close" %}
                {% set hideBtnClear = true %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if hideBtnClear == false %}
    [x] <--
{% endif %}
```

It works but isn't very elegant. Is there any way I can improve it?

Thanks

Comment: Why iterate over `attributes` if you know the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use the filter [`filter`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/filter.html) to solve this as well

```html
{% if btns|filter(v => v.attributes['aria-label']|default == 'Close') | length == 0 %}
    [ X ] 
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/muwmzx)

---

Using `not` instead `== 0` also works

`{% if not btns|filter(v => v.attributes['aria-label']|default == 'Close') | length %}`

Comment: Thanks for this and the twigfiddle link!

Answer (score 0):

Not much of a change, but if you know the required key in `btn.attributes`, then just check this key presence and it's value:

```
{% set hideBtnClear = false %}
{% for btn in modal.buttons %}
    {% if btn.attributes['aria-label'] is defined and btn.attributes['aria-label'] == "Close" %}
        {% set hideBtnClear = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if hideBtnClear == false %}
    [x] <--
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `{% if btn.attributes['aria-label']|default == 'Close' %}` would be shorter